# Show api data in JSX, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

trying to load the props data into the jsx, when I try to iterate it inside the return, getting an error of .map not defined.

```
const SavedListTable = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const {listData, setListData} = props;
   
    if(setListData.length > 0) {
        return(
            setListData.map((setListData, index) => {
                console.log(setListData)
                return(
                    <div>
                        <tr>
                        <td >{setListData.name}</td>
                        <td >Project</td>
                        <td>00 May 2022</td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>

                )

            })
                                    
        )

    }
```

this is the response from for console.log(props)

```
{notes: Array(8)}
notes: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: It would help if you showed where you were using `map`

Answer (score 1):

Use optional Chaining when using map function, it can cause errors sometimes due to the api response and when it comes, use optional chaining method in ES6. It will help you. And try to avoid console.log() in return, but if you want to use it, use like this {console.log()}

Answer (score 0):

not a good question you can use array.map() to return this table rows

as this `const SavedListTable = (props) => {

```
return(
    props.notes.map((row) => (
        <div>
            <tr>
                <td >{row.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    ))
)
```

}`

use this package it would be more easier

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component

this is an example,you just have to parse array to DataTable component

https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/getting-started-examples--page

Answer (score 0):

First pass the listData array and setListData function to props of this component and then you need to change setListData to listData, setListData is not the array but the function to set the list

```
const SavedListTable = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const {listData, setListData} = props;
   
    if(listData.length > 0) {
        return(
            listData.map((data, index) => {
                console.log(data)
                return(
                    <div>
                        <tr>
                        <td >{data.name}</td>
                        <td >Project</td>
                        <td>00 May 2022</td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>

                )

            })
                                    
        )

    }
```

Comment: Now getting an error of cannot read properties of undefined( reading 'length', and also console log listData is undefined.

Comment: You need to pass correct props something like this <Component listData={listData} setListData={setListData} />

Comment: Yes, passing props from the parent component, at first the props value listData in null, but after a second the listData get the data. meanwhile the function SavedListTable is executed, i think i have to use async wait for this.